# Recorded macro gives synax issue with a long nest IF formula

Tags: excel, formula, vba

I paste a code into E2 to modify a copy of the contents of A2 if a value ends in a letter (i.e. "554B" becomes "554.02", "348M" becomes "348.13", etc).

I paste this formula into Excel when recording:

```
=IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="A",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,".01"),IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="B",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,".02"),IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="C",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,".03"),IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="D",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,".04"),IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="E",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,".05"),IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="F",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,".06"),IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="G",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,".07"),IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="H",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,".08"),IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="I",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,".09"),IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="J",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,".10"),IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="K",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,".11"),IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="L",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,".12"),IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="M",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,".13"),IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="N",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,".14"),IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="O",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,".15"),IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="P",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,".16"),IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="Q",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,".17"),IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="R",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,".18"),IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="S",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,".19"),IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="T",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,".20"),IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="U",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,".21"),IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="V",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,".22"),IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="W",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,".23"),IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="X",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,".24"),IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="Y",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,".25"),IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="Z",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,".26")))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

and it works correctly in Excel. When I try to run the macro based on the recording it gives a syntax issue. I've modified the macro to fix the line breaks and some missing values when the recording breaks the lines, but still have issues.  Here is the standalone module:

```
Sub formatE2()
Range("E2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""A"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".01""),IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""B"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".02""), " & _
     IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""C"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".03""),IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""D"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".04""), " & _
     IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""E"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".05""),IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""F"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".06""), " & _
     IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""G"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".07""),IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""H"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".08""), " & _
     IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""I"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".09""),IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""J"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".10""), " & _
     IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""K"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".11""),IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""L"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1 "".12""), " & _
     IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""M"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".13""),IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""N"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".14""), " & _
     IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""O"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".15""),IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""P"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".16""), " & _
     IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""Q"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".17""),IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""R"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".18""), " & _
     IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""S"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".19""),IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""T"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".20""), " & _
     IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""U"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".21""),IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""V"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".22""), " & _
     IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""W"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".23""),IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""X"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".24""), " & _
     IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""Y"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".25""),IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""Z"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".26"")))))))))))))))))))))))))))"
```

End Sub

Any ideas why I keep getting a syntax issue?

Comment: There is a max character limit in VBA for formulas, and you might be hitting up against that.  However, this looks unnecessarily complicated, there's likely a better way to do what you're trying to do.  Can you describe a little more what you're trying to do generally? Also include a sample of the input and expected output.  Thanks!

Comment: you need to put `"` at the begining of each line.  So all the `IF(...` need to start, so `"IF(...`

Comment: @BruceWayne the limit is on `.FormulaArray` not `.FormulaR1C1`

Comment: A1 contains site IDs. Most are just numbers, some start with letters, some end with letters. This formula is supposed to convert all site IDs that end with a letter into a number (for eventual sort). i.e. 111B --> 111.02, 567M --> 567.13, 999Z --> 999.26.

Comment: I added double quotes to all the succeeding lines of formula. Still giving me a syntax issue.

Comment: FWIW - You can use `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISNUMBER(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)),RC[-4],TEXT(LEFT(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4])-1)+(CODE(RIGHT(RC[-4],1))-64)/100,""#.00""))"`.  (Scott Craner is working on a full answer, including both the corrections to your original code as well as a "short" formula, but that formula should do as a temporary solution.)

Comment: Thanks YowE3K and Scott! I tried that temporary formula and it works for all except the Sites which are purely numerical (i.e. 1017 becomes 100.91). The sites without any letters at the end should be left as is, can I modify the end of the code to say ....    ""#.00""),RC[-4]) in order to fix that issue?

Comment: Like this?    =IF(ISNUMBER(RIGHT(A2,1)),TEXT(LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-1)+(CODE(RIGHT(A2,1))-64)/100,"#.00"),A2)

Comment: You were also missing a `,`  see below

Comment: I also fixed the issue with the pure numbers.  See the formula below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the open quotes on each line and you were missing a `,` before the `""0.12""`:

```
Sub formatE2()
Range("E2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""A"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".01""),IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""B"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".02"")," & _
 "IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""C"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".03""),IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""D"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".04"")," & _
 "IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""E"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".05""),IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""F"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".06"")," & _
 "IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""G"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".07""),IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""H"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".08"")," & _
 "IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""I"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".09""),IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""J"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".10"")," & _
 "IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""K"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".11""),IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""L"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".12"")," & _
 "IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""M"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".13""),IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""N"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".14"")," & _
 "IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""O"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".15""),IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""P"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".16"")," & _
 "IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""Q"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".17""),IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""R"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".18"")," & _
 "IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""S"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".19""),IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""T"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".20"")," & _
 "IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""U"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".21""),IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""V"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".22"")," & _
 "IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""W"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".23""),IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""X"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".24"")," & _
 "IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""Y"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".25""),IF(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)=""Z"",REPLACE(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4]),1,"".26""),RC[-4]))))))))))))))))))))))))))"
```

Or you can use @YowE3K's version:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISNUMBER(--RIGHT(RC[-4],1)),RC[-4],LEFT(RC[-4],LEN(R‌​C[-4])-1)&TEXT(CODE(RIGH‌​T(RC[-4],1))-64)/100‌​,""#.00""))"
```

Comment: I was about to post a comment to the question with a simplified formula too (i.e. `=IF(ISNUMBER(RIGHT(RC[-4],1)),RC[-4],TEXT(LEFT(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4])-1)+(CODE(RIGHT(RC[-4],1))-64)/100,"#.00"))`) - so was intrigued as to why your one was so much shorter.  Yours doesn't add the lefthand portion of the number back on, and doesn't handle cases not ending in a letter, and returns a numeric value instead of a text value.  (That last part might actually be an advantage though.)

Comment: I always get caught out by the `ISNUMBER(A2)` (where A2 is the **text** `7`) returning `FALSE` - I'm glad the `--` fixes that.

Comment: I was also thinking that maybe the `TEXT(LEFT(RC[-4],LEN(R‌​C[-4])-1)+(CODE(RIGH‌​T(RC[-4],1))-64)/100‌​,""#.00"")` part should be replaced with `LEFT(RC[-4],LEN(R‌​C[-4])-1)&TEXT((CODE(RIGH‌​T(RC[-4],1))-64)/100‌​,"".00"")` - so that values which are non-numeric on the left-hand portion are still processed.  (The OP commented "Most are just numbers, some start with letters, some end with letters".)

Comment: Ohh - and fix your typo - "You're", not "Your" :D

Comment: Dude it is a community wiki now. Fix what you want 8P

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much!!

Comment: @ScottCraner Yeah - I noticed that you had made it a CW - but not until **after** I had posted the comment. :D